# Git clone and modify open source as a subdirectory and keep updated with master

Tags: git

In my project i use an open source which i want to modify (changes that are irrelevant to push to the actual open source project).

My project looks something like this under the git root:

1. dir A
2. dir B
3. cloned and modified open source

I wish to store the entire project in my remote git repo but also keep getting changed of the open source.

How can I accomplish that?
I think that submodule and subtree do not really do what I wanted.

I am open to other ideas how i can manage that.
Just to note that the projects are in the same git repository because the cloned open source uses other projects from my repo and the projects from the repo uses the open source.

Comment: Though perhaps not necessary, you might want to also tell us which language you are using.  I might recommend here that you just keep the open source project separate, and include it in your main project as a dependency (e.g. as a JAR in Java).

Comment: Hi, I am developing in java. As I said i need them in the same project as source code because there are dependencies in between them. (both open source references my projects and the other way around)

Comment: How does submodule not do what you want? I think it's just the right tool here, to be honest, can you indicate in what way it's not right for you? You'll have to rebase your local changes onto open-source/master, or merge open-source/master changes into your local branch, and submodule seems like the best tool to track that for you: have a private fork of the open source that you update from the official one and with their changes, and point the submodule to your private fork where you can push your changes and track everything nicely.

Comment: As I understand according to your suggestion I should split my repository into 2 parts. 1 - the entire project with a submodule and 2 - a repo of the open source. So the open source will be part of the project but will not be pushed into the main repo

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
What I did was add another remote of the open source
git fetch + git pull --allow-unrelated-histories

moved the open source to a subfolder

then push it to my original repository.

Comment: I have same problem can please elaborate how you did. I'm using on open source application with some modification. But the source library keeps updating new changes which I want in my application. along with my changes